# Aggregation table created in Pentaho Aggregation Designer not present in from clause of query

Tags: mysql, aggregate, pentaho, cube, mondrian

Please review below query generated while creating JPivot view on mondrian cube having aggregation table in its schema.

```sql
select
    `Dim_Time`.`Time_Id` as `c0`,
    `Dim_Time`.`month_no` as `c1`
from
    `Dim_Time` as `Dim_Time`
where
    `Dim_Time`.`Time_Id` = `AggTable1`.`Dim_Time_Month_(Key)`
group by
    `Dim_Time`.`Time_Id`,
    `Dim_Time`.`month_no`
order by
    ISNULL(`Dim_Time`.`Time_Id`) ASC, `Dim_Time`.`Time_Id` ASC
```

Why is AggTable1 not present in from clause? The table & specific column exists in database.

Answer (score 0):

In order to utilise the aggregate tables you have to enable following properties in mondrian.properties file.

```
mondrian.rolap.aggregates.Read=true
mondrian.rolap.aggregates.Use=true
```

Also based on mondrian version you have to define the aggregate tables on your schema file

mondrian 4

```
<MeasureGroup table='aggregate_table' type='aggregate'>
```

mondrian 3.x

```
<AggName name="aggregate_table">
```